# Coffee concentrate and water mixed together separated after 2 hours

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water

I'm asking because this makes no sense to me and making sure I'm not stupid.

I brewed 10 gallons of cold brew concentrate(TDS 12.2) and mixed it with 10 gallons of water.

I moved 10 gallons of the mixture into kegs and they ended up at TDS 6.4. 
Two hours later I filled the rest of the kegs. One keg was at TDS 4.8 while the rest were at TDS 0.4.

Will coffee and water separate? I've never seen this happen before and previous kegs have never tasted differently until just now.

Comment: Possibly a better fit for Chemistry SE or Seasonal Advice SE (the Cooking SE).

Comment: It could be decantation... Also, what do you mean by "TDS" ?

Comment: It could sediment, depending on what exactly is, but it is not a fast process, unless the suspended material is constituted by particles of the order of 1/10 of mm or more. If you did not mix properly, maybe it remained separated.

Comment: TDS is referring to Total Dissolved Solids

Comment: I'll check in the Chemistry SE as well.